# How to run multiple BackgroundService parallel in .net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

How is it possible to run multiple IHostedServices in parallel?

I use the WorkerService in .Net Core 3.0 and want both services to run parallel. Currently the second service is waiting for the first one to finish. Both services should run endlessly.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<ServiceA>();
                services.AddHostedService<ServiceB>();
            });
    }
```

A service looks like this:

```
public class ServiceA : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sample");
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
        } while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
}
```

// edit:
Very reluctantly I would use a `Task.Run(() => method());` method like this. But of course this way always works:

```
public class ServiceA : BackgroundService
{
    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I compare [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) to your code, I'd say you need to put the do/while in a separate async method and await that in ExecuteAsync ... But that is just a guess, I am still trying to understand what is happening. But I think it's worth to give that a try.

Comment: If you want timer-based execution, then [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) should apply.

Comment: @cSteusloff -> a bit late here .. but .. does this answer on another SO question, help? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004613/how-to-run-multiple-task-in-background-service-in-net-core-with-different-timer

Answer (score 9):

I asked myself a similar question and made some search but couldn't find a good answer.
I solved the issue running every background service in `Task.Run` with a cancellation token from `BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync()`
I have 2 services like you.

```
public class BackgroundService1: BackgroundService
{
    public BackgroundService1()
    {
    }
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }, stoppingToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

//Second service is just like the first one:

```
public class BackgroundService2: BackgroundService
{
    public BackgroundService2()
    {
    }
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }, stoppingToken);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and register them in Program.cs

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<BackgroundService1>();
                services.AddHostedService<BackgroundService2>();
            })
            .UseWindowsService()
```

Comment: that's nasty, but I like it! I think it could be IHostedService without BackgroundService

Comment: If you have an example of how you add your DbContext and repositories please share. I'm able to reproduce what you are doing there, and it works, but once I add database access it blows up with various service lifetime errors; I can't figure out what service lifetime to use when adding the DbContext  and repositories in the ConfigureServices method.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same kind of issue: Multiple service that do different work at different frequencies.

When looking into it, `BackgroundService` seems to be designed for sequential execution (an infinite loop based service's worst enemy).

After getting a hint from this thread, I found the solution that works for my case using [Microsoft's Timer Service example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/timer-service).

The base `TimerService` implements `IHostedService` and `IAsyncDisposable`:

- `StartAsync()` starts the timer on the `DoWork()`
- `DoWork()` is your overridable main work procedure.
- `StopAsync()` stops the timer gracefully.
- `DisposeAsync()` cleans up.

I've tested by deriving multiple `TimerService`s with different execution frequencies and adding them with `services.AddHostedService<>();`.

They all start and run at the same time, do their bit on clock.

**/!\** It is not `Task` based as it uses timer events. Just pointing this out because I've already had quite a difficult troubleshooting experience the one time I mixed time-based events and Tasks **/!\**

Answer (score 0):

No need to manually create a task. The default StartAsync calls ExecuteAsync and returns that task to be awaited somewhere else.

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs#L30

So, you can do `return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken)` before returning Task.Completed in StartAsync.

Comment: That's valid feedback, but it doesn't seem to address the core problem they're trying to solve regarding parallelism.

Comment: It does solve the parallelism. Instead of creating a task manually in ExecuteAsync, you can override StartAsync and invoke base.StartAsync, which will return ExecuteAsync as a task.