# How to run multiple task in background service in .net core with different timer duration

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am creating a worker service which will be run as a windows service. I have a requirement where I would like to invoke two tasks which may have different timers.

Say `DoWork` should be called every 5 minutes and `DoAnotherWork` should be called every 10 minutes or so. These two tasks can run in parallel and are not dependant on each other.

I was able to create task `DoWork` which can run after every 5 minutes. I am a bit confused about how to implement another task that will have different timer duration?

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{        
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;        
    private IDataLoaderService _dataLoaderService;        

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        _dataLoaderService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataLoaderService>();                        
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {            
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await DoWork(stoppingToken, _dataLoaderService);
            await Task.Delay(300000, stoppingToken); //Run every 5 minutes

            await DoAnotherWork(stoppingToken, _dataLoaderService);
            await Task.Delay(600000, stoppingToken); //Run every 10 minutes
        }
    }

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken, IDataLoaderService loaderService)
    {
        await loaderService.Process();            
    }        
    
    private async Task DoAnotherWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken, IDataLoaderService loaderService)
    {
        await loaderService.Validate();            
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use Hangfire or Quartz you can use one of the timers (for [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-3.1)).

Comment: @GuruStron Can you elaborate How I can use `Timer` in `ExecuteAsync` or `StartAsync` method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> These two tasks can run in parallel and are not dependant on each other.

Sounds to me like you have two services:

```
public class ProcessDataLoaderWorker : BackgroundService
{
  private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var dataLoaderService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataLoaderService>();

    while (true)
    {
      await dataLoaderService.Process();
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), stoppingToken); //Run every 5 minutes
    }
  }
}

public class ValidateDataLoaderWorker : BackgroundService
{
  private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var dataLoaderService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataLoaderService>();

    while (true)
    {
      await dataLoaderService.Validate();
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), stoppingToken); //Run every 10 minutes
    }
  }
}
```

I also modified the way the `IDataLoaderService` was used so that it is not used outside its scope, and changed the `Task.Delay` arguments to be more self-explanatory.

Comment: I'd add an `await Task.Yield()` before the loop, because an exception before the first `await` would cause a startup failure.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: I generally [wrap it in `Task.Run` for the same reason](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary 2 questions here: 1) how are these both 'wired up'? 2) why the `while (true)` instead of `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)` .. if a cancellation is requested ... then this will gracefully end these two background-tasks?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: 1) You can add multiple services with `AddHostedService`. 2) The standard pattern of cancellation in .NET is to throw `OperationCanceledException`, so that is why I strongly avoid `IsCancellationRequested`. I recognize your username from somewhere...

Comment: re: Throw vs `IsCancellationRequested` .. um .. so why are the MS templates pushing `ICR` instead of throwing?  re: Username .. i hope it's not for bad things :hides: I've been around a while (aka. I'm old) i ask a lot of things, too :blush:

Comment: @Pure.Krome: I don't know why the templates have that code. Regarding yourself, it's not bad at all; it might be from MSDN forum days?

Comment: I might see if I could ping someone on the docs team, like @guardrex. And yep - I was active in the MSDN forums days, too :) :blush:

Comment: @StephenCleary What If I have more than 10 task to run parallel. Do I need to create multiple service class for all those?

Comment: @AnantJaiswal: That design choice is up to you. For this particular question, it seemed to me like they were different services. And it's possible to have 10 different services. It's also possible to have one service with multiple timers (in which case you should use a real timer and not `Task.Delay`).

Comment: I'd say this: if the services do different, independent things, then they should probably be different services. If the services are dependent (i.e., "C is always done after B"), or if they are all different things, then I'd consider making them different services.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use existing scheduling libraries in your case you can go with having two timers, like in this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks), where `System.Threading.Timer` is utilized. Something like that:

```
public class Worker : IHostedService, IDisposable
{        
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;        
    private IDataLoaderService _dataLoaderService;  
    private Timer _timer1;
    private Timer _timer2;      

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _dataLoaderService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataLoaderService>();              
        _timer1 = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
        _timer2 = new Timer(DoAnotherWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }    
   
    private async void DoWork(object _)
    {
        // or create scope and resolve here
        await _loaderService.Process();            
    }        
    
    private async void DoAnotherWork(object _)
    {
        // or create scope and resolve here
        await _loaderService.Validate();            
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer1?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        _timer2?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer1?.Dispose();
        _timer2?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any advantage of using `IHostedService` over `BackgroundService`?

Comment: @Shaggy you don't need to think where to start timers =)

Comment: Got it. I tried your code and not sure why but it is executing only at once. `DoWork` is not getting invoked every 5 minutes.

Comment: `BackgroundService` is more applicable, now.

Comment: @Pure.Krome why is so?

Comment: @Shaggy strange, with lesser timeouts it works fine for me. Checked with 300 second timeouts in console app - works fine also (with dummy task of `Task.Delay` and `Console.WriteLine`).

Comment: @guru I was under the impression that BackgroundServices are the recommended way instead of using IHostedService. The docs also explain how to make timer based background services - in fact there's a few scenario's. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks

Comment: @Pure.Krome that is exactly the same article, I linked in my answer (the `docs` link), the first example is about timer based service, which is using `IHostedService` and what I based my answer on.