# Run multiple task in background service in .NET Core with different timer duration

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm using the BackgroundService - is it possible to have multiple task in **one background service project** in .NET Core with different timer duration:

FirstLoop - execute every second

SecondLoop - execute every minute

ThirdLoop - execute every hour

ForthLoop - execute every day

I read the question which is related to the topic but it seems from 3 years ago and I'm wondering if there is a new approach to achieve this

[How to run multiple task in background service in .net core with different timer duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004613/how-to-run-multiple-task-in-background-service-in-net-core-with-different-timer)

For some reason only the FirstLoop is been executed and every loop after it is not been executed. What are my options to make this work?

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
if (double.TryParse(_configuration["FirstLoop"], out double firstLoopExecution))
{
    using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(firstLoopExecution));
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested &&
        await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
    {
        //Wrap any invocations inside this while loop into a try catch so that when one run of the while loop fails, it doesn’t break the entire method meaning the periodic loop continues
        try
        {
            await DoFirstWorkAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error in first loop , " + ex.Message + ", InnerException ex:" + ex.GetOriginalException()?.Message + ", stackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
}
else
{
    _logger.LogError("Missing FirstLoop configuration");
}

if (double.TryParse(_configuration["SecondLoop"], out double secondLoopExecution))
{
    using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondLoopExecution));
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested &&
        await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
    {
        //Wrap any invocations inside this while loop into a try catch so that when one run of the while loop fails, it doesn’t break the entire method meaning the periodic loop continues
        try
        {
            await DoSecondWorkAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error in second loop , " + ex.Message + ", InnerException ex:" + ex.GetOriginalException()?.Message + ", stackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
}
else
{
    _logger.LogError("Missing SecondtLoop configuration");
}

if (double.TryParse(_configuration["ThirdLoop"], out double thirdLoopExecution))
{
    using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(thirdLoopExecution));
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested &&
        await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
    {
        //Wrap any invocations inside this while loop into a try catch so that when one run of the while loop fails, it doesn’t break the entire method meaning the periodic loop continues
        try
        {
            await DoThirdWorkAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error in first loop , " + ex.Message + ", InnerException ex:" + ex.GetOriginalException()?.Message + ", stackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
}
else
{
    _logger.LogError("Missing ThirdLoop configuration");
}

if (double.TryParse(_configuration["ForthLoop"], out double forthLoopExecution))
{
    using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(forthLoopExecution));
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested &&
        await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
    {
        //Wrap any invocations inside this while loop into a try catch so that when one run of the while loop fails, it doesn’t break the entire method meaning the periodic loop continues
        try
        {
            await DoForthWorkAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error in first loop , " + ex.Message + ", InnerException ex:" + ex.GetOriginalException()?.Message + ", stackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
}
else
{
    _logger.LogError("Missing ForthLoop configuration");
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the first part of your `ExecuteAsync` method, the code does not exit the `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))` block because the conditions are not changing under normal running which is why your other timers are never started.

The simplest change is to refactor the `ExecuteAsync` method into 4 different methods and then call them all in parallel

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>() {
        ExecuteFirstAsync(stoppingToken),
        ExecuteSecondAsync(stoppingToken),
        ExecuteThirdAsync(stoppingToken),
        ExecuteFourthAsync(stoppingToken)
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

but a better solution might be to break them up into multiple classes and register them independently

```
services.AddHostedService<FirstService>();
services.AddHostedService<SecondService>();
services.AddHostedService<ThirdService>();
services.AddHostedService<FourthService>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a few of these classes. One for each interval.

Then register it as a HostedService.

```
public class DoSomeWorkService : BackgroundService
{
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
         while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
              var delay = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
              await DoStuffAsync(stoppingToken);
              await delay;
         }
    }

    private Task DoStuff(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
}
```